# Evaluating $\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc}{a^4+b^4+c^4-4abc}$, given $a+b+c=a^2+b^2+c^2=1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How do I solve this problem?

Says so:

> If  $$a+b+c=a^2+b^2+c^2=1$$
> find the value of
> $$M=\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc}{a^4+b^4+c^4-4abc}$$

**edit:**

I know these identities
$$1)(a + b + c)^2 = a^2 + + c^2 +  b^2+2 a b + + 2 a c + 2 b c$$
$$2)(a + b + c)^3 =3 a^2 b+3 a^2 c+a^3+3 a b^2+6 a b c+3 a c^2+3 b^2 c+b^3+3 b c^2+c^3$$
$$3)(a + b + c)^4=6 a^2 b^2+12 a^2 b c+4 a^3 b+6 a^2 c^2+4 a^3 c+a^4+12 a b^2 c+4 a b^3+12 a b c^2+4 a c^3+6 b^2 c^2+4 b^3 c+b^4+4 b c^3+c^4$$

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @dxiv , hi , I have tried squaring and cubing a+b+c, only concluding that ab+ac+bc=0,I think this has some artifice that I do not see.

Comment: You've been around here for long enough to know that such context and approach belong into the question, not as a comment. One hint: [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials).

Comment: I have not arrived yet :( .Only using remarkable products

Comment: Extended hint (equivalent, in fact, to working out Newton's identities by hand): you have $a+b+c=1$ and found that $ab+bc+ca=0$. Let $p=abc$ then by [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas) $a,b,c$ are the roots of the cubic $t^3 - t^2 - p=0$. That means $a^3=a^2+p$, then writing the same for $b.c$ and adding them together $\dots$

Comment: @dxiv ,In this problem I just have to use remarkable identities, I have not ever spent the identities of Newton and the relations of Vieta

Comment: Then [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4371927/edit) your question and write in there what you are (not) allowed to use, and which "*remarkable identities*" you know. It's hard to guess what kind of answer you are looking for until/unless you do that.

Comment: Regarding the edit: identity #2 is $\,a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3 - 3(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) + 3 abc\,$ and is, in fact, one of Newton's identities ($\,{p_{3}=e_{1}^{3}-3e_{1}e_{2}+3e_{3}}\,$) linked in a previous comment. Find a similar form for identity #3 and you are done.

Comment: @dxiv       i got this:  $$a^4+b^4+c^4 =(a + b + c)^4 + 4 (a b + b c + c a)^2 - 
 4 (a b + b c + c a) (a + b + c)^2 - 2 (a^2 b^2 + b^2 c^2 + c^2 a^2)$$  ,I don't know where to get the last part

Comment: That's close, but you want to express everything in terms of $a+b+c$ and $ab+bc+ca$ (which you know) and $abc$ (which you can only hope will cancel out), so it is more useful to replace:

$$
4(ab+bc+ca)^2-2\left(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+c^2a^2\right)=2(ab+bc+ca)^2+4abc(a+b+c)
$$

Comment: @divx , great , it came out , it gave me one in total , it cost me a lot to factor , how do you factor so fast , with some program?, Thanks

Comment: I posted an outline of the solution as an answer. You can redo the same steps for a general $\,p(x)\,$ cubic, and you'll get the general formulas - no need to factor anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comments, given that $\,a+b+c=1\,$ and $\,ab+bc+ca=0\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
p(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c) &= x^3 - (a+b+c)x^2 + (ab+bc+ca)x - abc
\\ &= x^3 - x^2 - abc
\end{align}
$$

Since $\,p(a)=p(b)=p(c)=0\,$:

$$
\begin{cases}
a^3 = a^2 + abc
\\ b^3 = b^2 + abc
\\ c^3 = c^2 + abc
\end{cases}
$$

Adding the three equalities:

$$
a^3+b^3+c^3=a^2+b^2+c^2 + 3 abc = 1 + 3 abc \;\;\iff\;\; a^3+b^3+c^3 - 3abc = 1
$$

Multiplying the same equalities by $a,b,c$, respectively, and adding up:

$$
a^4+b^4+c^4 = a^3+b^3+c^3 + abc(a+b+c) = 1 + 4abc \;\;\iff\;\; a^4+b^4+c^4-4abc = 1
$$

*Note: first identity is equivalent to [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas), the others [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials) in disguise*.